# What is the best way to set the default value of a boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Fundamentally speaking, is there a pragmatic difference between the following:

`let closed = true`

and

`let open = false`

or

`let closed = false`

and

`let open = true`

I do not suspect there is a performance difference.

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Performance difference in what? Between true and false?

Answer (score 1):

That's all the same and depends on the semantic you want to give to your code.